# "Scope" in directive linking function is the root scope, not directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, directive

I have a directive as follows

```
.directive('ticketingChat', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl:  '/Reply/ReplyScreen', //cshtml from MVC page
        controller: 'TicketingChatController',
        link: function (scope, el, attr) {
            scope.writingTo = "Hey there!";
        }
    }
})
```

I thought that this would create it's own scope, and "scope" would allow me to access it.

Instead, ng-inspector shows me that:

[image]

"Scope" is in fact, the root scope. How can I force the directive to create it's own child scope?
And how can I access that scope from the linking function?

Comment: it depends from how you use your directive in html, it used current scope, and also, possibly this not _$rootScope_ but **child** of _$rootScope with id=002

Comment: also, if you see doc: for creating own scope, you should use `scope:{}` in returned object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `scope: true` in the directive definition object will make AngularJS create an inheriting child scope. Setting `scope` to an object will create an isolated child scope.

For example:

```
.directive('ticketingChat', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/Reply/ReplyScreen',
        controller: 'TicketingChatController',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, el, attr) {
           scope.writingTo = "Hey there!"; // This will be set on the child scope because we have scope: true.
        }
    }
})
```

See [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) for more details regarding the `scope` attribute.

Comment: What if I need to do `scope.ticket.Id = attr["ticketid"];`

Comment: If `scope: true` then the child scope will have the source's scope as its parent scope, so `scope.ticket` would resolve to a parent scope's `ticket` member (if it exists on a parent).

Comment: `scope: {ticketId : "=ticketid"},` if you only want this id shared with your child scope.

Comment: I need the directive to create it's own scope, not use it's parent scope. Then I need to set a property in that scope from the linking function. Thanks

Comment: What you describe is shown in my answer. `scope.writingTo` will be set on the child scope in the link function.

Comment: See [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) for more details regarding the `scope` attribute.